# Prototype Pollution using Visualforce Remote Action

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting

I'd like to know if anyone has faced issues with [javascript arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) when declaring Remote Action, have you? How have you overcome it?

Asking because the following code started to fail on key `remove` (which I could not see on plain debug):

```
var panels = [];
panels["keyOne"] = jquery('#divIdOne');
panels["keyTwo"] = jquery('#divIdTwo');
for (panel in panels) {
  panel.slideUp();
}
```

I found that Salesforce replaces `remove` method of Array prototype (on VFRemote.js). Thus had to add [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty):

```
var panels = [];
panels["keyOne"] = jquery('#divIdOne');
panels["keyTwo"] = jquery('#divIdTwo');
for (panel in panels) {
  if (panels.hasOwnProperty(panel)) {
    panel.slideUp();
  }
}
```

Is there any drawback for this approach?